# Reflexive Association C#

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to implement a reflexive association in C# sharp but couldn't find any example on the web.
I have come up with following

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Employee Boss { get; set; }
   public List<Employee> Junoirs;
   public Employee (string name)
   {
       Junoirs = new List<Employee>();
       Name = name;
   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee tom = new Employee("Tom");
        Employee marry = new Employee("Marry");
        Employee jhon = new Employee("Jhon");
        Employee foo = new Employee("Foo");
        Employee bar = new Employee("Bar");

        tom.Junoirs.AddRange(new Employee[] { marry, jhon });
        marry.Boss = tom;
        jhon.Boss = tom;

        marry.Junoirs.AddRange(new Employee[] { foo, bar });
        foo.Boss = marry;
        bar.Boss = marry;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid example of reflexive association?
How can I automatically add `tom` as `Boss` of employees `marry` and `jhon` as I add them to list of `Junoirs` of tom?

Comment: Please please please change the name of that class to `Juniors`

Comment: Create a method called e.g. "AddJunior(…)" which sets both sides of the relationship

Comment: @PhiterFernandes btw `Junoirs` is not a class, thanks for pointing out the typo though

Comment: Yeah yeah list sorry

Comment: My favorite question - why? `couldn't find any example on the web` <-- then maybe it's not an important concept to know in 2016. I haven't heard this term being used even once. By using google, it looks like you implemented [**Asymmetric** Reflexive Association](http://cruise.eecs.uottawa.ca/umple/ReflexiveAssociations.html) here. Also see this for typical use examples: http://flylib.com/books/en/2.861.1.52/1/ I would argue that knowing what you code exactly does is 100x more important than terminology used behind the underlying concept. Especially in Canada, where both of us are from.

Comment: @Neolisk I totally agree, the reason I am implementing reflexive-association is because it is in my school syllabus

Comment: Oh I see, then do a regular reflexive association, for example, movie sequel / prequel model. Don't do lists and/or hierarchy just yet. See if it's enough for your course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods to add/remove juniors.
If you *need* add/remove-functionality on the Juniors property, you can implement your own IList or ICollection which handles the book-keeping.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee Boss
    {
        get { return _boss; }
        set
        {
            _boss?.RemoveJunior(this);
            value?.AddJunior(this);
        }
    }


    public IReadOnlyList<Employee> Juniors => _juniors.AsReadOnly();

    private Employee _boss = null;
    private readonly List<Employee> _juniors = new List<Employee>();

    public Employee(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void AddJunior(Employee e)
    {
        // Remove from existing boss' list of employees
        // Can't set Boss property here, that would create infinite loop
        e._boss?.RemoveJunior(e);
        _juniors.Add(e);
        e._boss = this;
    }

    public void RemoveJunior(Employee e)
    {
        _juniors.Remove(e);
        e._boss = null;
    }
}

public class EmployeeTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void SettingBoss_AddsToEmployee()
    {
        var b = new Employee("boss");
        var e1 = new Employee("1");

        e1.Boss = b;

        Assert.Same(b, e1.Boss);
        Assert.Contains(e1, b.Juniors);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AddEmployee_SetsBoss()
    {
        var b = new Employee("boss");
        var e1 = new Employee("1");

        b.AddJunior(e1);

        Assert.Same(b, e1.Boss);
        Assert.Contains(e1, b.Juniors);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void NullBoss_RemovesEmployee()
    {
        var b = new Employee("boss");
        var e1 = new Employee("1");

        b.AddJunior(e1);
        e1.Boss = null;

        Assert.Null(e1.Boss);
        Assert.DoesNotContain(e1, b.Juniors);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void RemoveEmployee_NullsBoss()
    {
        var b = new Employee("boss");
        var e1 = new Employee("1");

        b.AddJunior(e1);

        b.RemoveJunior(e1);

        Assert.Null(e1.Boss);
        Assert.DoesNotContain(e1, b.Juniors);
    }
}
```